# handling 2 different types with rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rabl

I am doing a search against a table called locations and a table called items. They are both short tables (2k items) so not nervous about performance of this query.

I am going to search against one and then another and thus return 2 different types of objects as a single array. Is there a way I can use a rabl template to handle either of these situations. Something like:

```
collection @locations

@locations.each do |x|
if x.class.to_s=='Location'
  extends "api/location"
elsif x.class.to_s=='Location'
  extends "api/item"
end
```

thx

**edit #1**
Tried this but not sure what this gets me. The array is just a list of different objects and not sure what flattening arrays achieves.

```
collection @b

node(:data) do |m|
  [@locations, @items].flatten
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around a bit and came up with this, which should present a JSON array named `array_name` with all of the objects in `@locations` and `@items`:

*.rabl:

```
node(:array_name) do |m|
  [@locations, @items].flatten
end
```

Comment: I tried making adjustments above in edit#1 but not really sure what flattening the array is going to get me.

Comment: If you don't flatten it, the node is actually an array with two items, the first item being an array of locations and the second array being an array of items.

Quoting your question, you wrote "...return 2 different types of objects as a single array," which is what this template does. If you're looking for a different format, can you clarify for me?